# Crandall & Rabinowitz Theorem, bifurcation curves

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde, hyperbolic-pde

Crandall & Rabinowitz Theorem states what follows. We have got a Banach Space $(X,||\cdot||)$ and an equation of the following type:
$$
F(\lambda,u) = \lambda u - G(u) = 0,
$$
where $G \in C^1(X,X)$ is such that $G(0)=0$ and $G'(0)$ is compact (where ' is a Fréchet derivative).
If $\lambda_0$ is an eigenvalue for $G'(0)$ of odd multiplicity, then one of the following occur:

- From $(\lambda_0,0)$ there is an unbounded bifurcation curve of non-trivial solution of $F=0$ (here trivial means of the type $(\lambda,0)$),
- From $(\lambda_0,0)$ there is a bifurcation curve which meets again the trivial branch at $(\lambda_*,0)$ , where $\lambda_*$ is another eigenvalue of $G'(0)$.

Can someone give me a (not exceedingly complex) example of when the second case occurs? I mean, it looks as though it is the case which occurs most likely, though I have not yet managed to find an example in which I can actually describe the curve.

I am sorry if the question is inadequate for this site, yet I have already tried on stackexchange (and got no response).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example in $R^2$: $G(u)=(-u_1+u_2^3,u_2-u_1^3)$.